# Mount loop device with FUSE

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, fuse

So let's say I have a file attached to a loop device /dev/loop1 how could I mount that using fuse (filesystem in user space) ?

Comment: This is a system administration question, not a programming question, and more properly belongs on ServerFault. Also, it would be more helpful if you provided details -- what kind of filesystem you're trying to mount, what you've tried already and how that thing failed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using fuse, you don't need a loop device at all, and can directly mount the file itself. So, you can do either this:

```
$ sudo ext4fuse test.ext4 /mnt
```

Or, if for some bizarre reason you *really* want to use a loop device, this:

```
$ sudo losetup /dev/loop0 test.ext4
$ sudo ext4fuse /dev/loop0 /mnt
```

Comment: I have fuse executable made from source.  I don't use fuseext2. How can I use that let's say my fuse executable is fusexmp, the filesystem contained in the file is fat32.

Comment: Are you sure the first command line is correct? It tells me `losetup: /dev/test.ext2: failed to set up loop device: No such file or directory`

Comment: @JoachimWagner, I'm a bit miffed at my past self for lack of proofreading. Corrected and tested (and modernized a bit, moving to ext4fuse rather than fuseext2).

Comment: `losetup --read-only` is a reason for doing it in 2 steps, e.g. when you don't want any write operations, not even from re-playing a journal.

Comment: Doesn't using `sudo` defeat the point of using `fuse`?

Comment: @OrangeDog, ...some of the potential points, but not all of them (f/e, if you're mounting a suspected-corrupt filesystem and want to avoid kernel panics). It's not essential here, but more of a simplification factor; leaving it out results in changes in effective file permissions, and in potential configuration dependencies that it's easier to leave out-of-scope.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the permissions of the loop device so that the fuse process can access it, you can mount it the same way as any other device.